# TImeStamp for Request and Response Transaction in SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Is there a way to get how such time it took to get a response from a webservice call. Its for logging purpose where I am just trying to see how much time its taking to make a request and response and put that time in java code.

Comment: If the call is synchronous take the system time before and after calling the webservice.

Comment: It is a asynchronous call.

Comment: Can it be done through Log4j ?

Comment: I assume your client runs Java, so use `System.currentTimeMillis()` and log the way you like. You'd need to store the starting time somewhere though and retrieve it when processing the response event. Or, if it is possible, make the webservice send the duration.

Comment: Is possible to use Log4j in this scenario

Comment: Hmm, I'd say the logging framework is not relevant since what you'd have to do is store the time you started the request and retrieve it upon receiving the response. There might be ways to do this using a logging framework but I don't know of any (unless you build that into the framework yourself, e.g. by adding a custom appender). - As an alternative, though not as nicely automated, might be to log the start and end times independently and then calculate the difference yourself or parse the logfile.